# Add custom content Next add-to-cart In button for a specific Product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add content next to add to cart button in woocommerce for specific product, I have used the bellow woocommerce hook, But unfortunately it didn't work:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func' );
function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {
    $current_product = $product->id;
    if($current_product === '13333') {
        echo '<div class="second_content">Place your content here!</div>';
    }
}
```

Any one can help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Update: Added compatibility with WC +3

This custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_single_product_summary`** action hook, will display a custom content after **`add-to-cart`** button for a specific **`product ID`** in the single product page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func', 35 );
function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {
    global $product;

    // Added compatibility with WC +3
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    if($product_id == 13333)
        echo '<div class="custom-content">'.__('Place your content here!','woocommerce').'</div>';

}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.